# Get value from bootstrap modal, save, refresh page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal window on a mvc razor page. I'm trying to create a modal with a textbox, a save and cancel button, and if a value is saved, I'd like to refresh the page after this happens.

The strategy I was attempting was to use javascript to send the needed fields to the mvc controller, and in turn send them to the c# function to save, and after that, refresh the page.
I set a break point in google chrome, and I know I'm at least calling the javascript function, but from there something is going wrong.

On the razor page I have the modal

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div id="AdjustedAmountModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">New Adusted Liability Amount:</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AdjustedLiabilityAmount)
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align:center">
                                        <div>
                                            <button id="saveAdjustedAmount" type="button" class="btn btn-primary view-insp">Save</button>
                                            <button id="Button_closeModal" type="button" class="btn btn-default close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

My javascript function (which is at least being called), is as follows

```
$(document).on("click", "#saveAdjustedAmount", function () {

$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { "pDOT": $("#DOTNumber").val(), "pKYU": $("#KYUNumber").val(), "pKIT": $("#KITNumber").val(), "pCarrierName": $("#CarrierName").val(), "pAmount": $("#LiabilityAmount").val(), "pAdjustedLiabilityAmount": $("#AdjustedLiabilityAmount").val() },
    url: ResolveUrl('~/JeopardyAssessmentController/SaveValue'),
    success: function (redirectUrl) {
        //Simply redirect to refresh the page
        window.location.href = redirectUrl;
    }
});
```

});

In chrome developer tools, I'm seeing a red squiggly underneath the line

```
url: ResolveUrl('~/JeopardyAssessmentController/SaveValue'),
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: ResolveURL is not defined

I also have a break in visual studio in the controller function that I'm attempting to call

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveValue(string pDOT, string pKYU, string pKIT, string pCarrierName, decimal pAmount, string pAdjustedLiabilityAmount)
    {
        OBS_LIB.BLL.JeopardyAssessment.JeopardyAssessment.SaveJeopardyAssessment(pDOT, pKYU, pKIT, pCarrierName, pAmount, User.Identity.Name, pAdjustedLiabilityAmount);
        return Json(Url.Action("Create", "JeapordyAssessment"));
    }
```

This one is not even being called, and I'm beginning to question my entire strategy here. Am I going about this even remotely correctly? Is it possible to achieve what I'm attempting, and if so, how?

I'm a little new to this, and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: is ResolveUrl in your js file or on a view?

Comment: It's in the js file.

Answer (score 0):

```
return Json(Url.Action("Create", "JeapordyAssessment"));
```

Not sure if its related but is that supposed to be JeapordyAssessment and not JeopardyAssessment?

Comment: That was a misspelling, but not the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ResolveUrl is a .net function. It will not work inside of your JS files. To get around this you can add this to your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var baseUrl = "<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>";
</script>
```

Then in your javascript do:

```
function ResolveUrl(url) {
    if (url.indexOf("~/") === 0) {
        url = baseUrl + url.substring(2);
    }
    return url;
}
```

Is this the best approach? **No** but it should solve your problem.

Code borrowed from https://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/resolveurl-in-javascript as I am lazy.